# How to Make a Composable and its associated Business Logic Reusable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 Screens ->

Screen A and Screen B and a reusable composable Music List which I want to reuse in both the screens. Android Documentation recommends to make the composable stateless so that it can be reused.

```
@Composable
MusicList(viewModel) {
   LazyColumn {
      ...
   }
}

@Composable
ScreenA() {
   viewModel = screenAViewModel()
   MusicList(viewModel)
   ....
}

@Composable
ScreenB() {
   viewModel = screenBViewModel()
   MusicList(viewModel)
   ....
}
```

I am using a screen-wide viewModel to store and update its state. But even though the UI is reusable, I want the business logic in the viewModel to be reusable as well so that I can reuse it in both Screen A and Screen B. What is the recommended approach here?

I feel this composable should have its own viewModel but it seems Google does not recommend it.

Comment: you can make composable MusicList stateless by making it accept only the list instead of the viewModel so this composable can be re-used for the different list.

Answer (score 1):

I use data layer (clean architecture) [Data Layer - Google guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer).

[Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) is the best option. Parameters can be repository(data layer) or usecase.

```kotlin
class ScreenAViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val fetchMusicList: FetchMusicListDataLayer,
): ViewModel() {
  val uiState = StateFlow<UiState>..()
  fun fetchMusicList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      fetchMusicList(..)
        .onSuccess { uiState.update { ShowList(it) } }
    }
  }
  sealed interface UiState {
    data class ShowList(val list: List<Music>): UiState
    ...
  }
}
class ScreenBViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val fetchMusicList: FetchMusicListDataLayer,
): ViewModel() {
  // same as ScreenAViewModel
  ...
}
```

And I always divide screens(with ViewModels) into stateless UI, because I can easily check UI with preview tools without creating ViewModels.
But, if these two screens are totally the same, I won't create screenB.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MusicList(list: List<Music>) { // stateless
   LazyColumn {
      ...
   }
}
@Composable
fun ScreenA(viewModel: ScreenAViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
  val state by viewModel.uiState.observe..()
  when (state) {
    is ShowList -> MusicList(state.list)
    ...
  }
}
@Composable
fun ScreenB(viewModel: ScreenBViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
  // same as ScreenA
  ....
}
```

> I feel this composable should have its own viewModel but it seems Google does not recommend it.

AFAIK, they don't provide any practical information. I think Compose UI needs its ViewModel to store UI states. But its UI looks like a view router/controller. If we won't use a ViewModel which contains UI state and data layer, these functions should be placed in Activity/Fragment or Compose UI itself. That's ridiculous.